# get the elements of a std::tuple by passing the type of another std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a structure that makes it easier to manage the tuple:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
struct Store
{
    using base_type = std::tuple<Ts...>;

    base_type store;

    Store(Ts... args)
    {
        store = {args...};
    }

    template<size_t... Ints>
    decltype(auto) Get()
    {
        if constexpr(sizeof...(Ints) == 1)
            return std::get<Ints...>(store);
        else
            return std::make_tuple(std::get<Ints>(store)...);
    }

    template<class... Us>
    decltype(auto) Get()
    {
        if constexpr(sizeof...(Us) == 1)
            return std::get<Us...>(store);
        else
            return std::make_tuple(std::get<Us>(store)...);
    }
};
```

I also have structures that allow me to combine template arguments:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct store_helper
{ using type = Store<Ts...>; };

template <typename... Ts>
struct store_helper<Store<Ts...>>
{ using type = Store<Ts...>; };

template<typename ... Ts1, typename... Ts2>
struct store_helper<Store<Ts1...>, Ts2...>
: public store_helper<Store<Ts1..., Ts2...>>
{ };

template<typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2, typename... Ts3>
struct store_helper<Store<Ts1...>, Store<Ts2...>, Ts3...>
: public store_helper<Store<Ts1..., Ts2...>, Ts3...>
{ };

template<typename... Ts>
using Scheme = typename store_helper<Ts...>::type;
```

Now I can do this:

```cpp
int main() {

    using Vector2D = Scheme<int, int>;

    using Position = Scheme<Vector2D>;
    using Direction = Scheme<Vector2D>;

    using Player = Scheme<Position, Direction, float>;

    Player store(33, 44, 12, 122, 4.0);

    auto float_num = store.Get<float>();

    std::cout << float_num << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I'd also like to do that:

```cpp
    auto [x, y] = store.Get<Direction>();

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
```

I need to retrieve data by passing the tuple from which it he created. Is there any way to implement this syntax ?

Comment: `Direction` has to become a class to have a type disctinct from `Vector2D` (and `Position`). But why would you do all this? Also your constructor lacks perfect forwarding, and should use the member init list.

Comment: This is over-engineering.  Just make a simple `struct { x, y }`, not every composite type should be a `std::tuple`.

Comment: Your `Get` methods are inefficient. You are copying every single onject everytime. use `std::tie` instead of `std::make_tuple`.